# Connection between connected and compact spaces?

Tags: general-topology

What kind of connection is there between connected and compact subspaces, if any?

I am just curious. I know that the image of a compact space under a continuous function is compact and the same holds for connected spaces. But this is not what I am looking for. I would like to see a condition on a set or a topological space in order to see if we can infer that if a set is connected + some other condition then it is compact. (Something similar to any compact set in a Hausdorff space is closed. In this case the extra condition would be having a Hausdorff space).

(Sorry for the initial confusion. I meant compact set, not connected, in my example.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no such connections.

Comment: A fairly bold claim! =]

Comment: @TaraB: And I y'aint afraid to make it!

Answer (score 4):

There is a subspecialty of toplogy called continuum theory, which studies connected compact spaces.  See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_%28topology%29) for some general information.